# AppStore update and Realm

Tags: ios, database, app-store, realm

I have application in Appstore based on Realm Mobile Database. I'd like to prepare version 1.1. Will update delete all data in user's local database ?

Answer (score 3):

The upgrade won't delete anything on your current database. The migration is automatic. If you need to change one or more field in your current model, you need to upgrade the database schema version. Place this code into the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your AppDelegate:

```
    //Realm migration
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2, //here's the schema version you need to change
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                 //if you want to perform particular tasks
                 //while migrating, place your code here.
            }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    _ = try! Realm()
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, It won't delete existing database, that's why Realm support automatic/custom migration.